# In Backbone this.model is undefined, why?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I've looked everywhere for an answer but wasn't satisfied with what I've found.

The issue is, I'm doing a tutorial from Addy Osmani to make a 'Todo' app in Backbone, but when I look at the console, I get an error saying that `this.model is undefined`.

I even tried this SO answer [Backbone model error displayed in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396586/backbone-model-error-displayed-in-console), but I still get the same error. Please tell me what is wrong.

By the way, what are `this.model` or `this.collection`? I've got an idea that they refer to `Backbone.Model` and `Backbone.Collection` but how do they work? I'm asking this because in another tutorial `this.collection` and `this.model.models` were also undefined, when I've clearly defined the `Model` and `Collection`.

Many Thanks

JS:

```
//Model
var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({

  defaults: {
    title: 'Enter title here',
    completed: true
  },

  validate: function(attrs) {
    if (attrs.title === undefined) {
        return 'Remember to enter a title';
    }
  },

  initialize: function() {
    console.log('This model has been initialized');

    this.on('change:title', function() {
        console.log('-Title values for this model have changed');
    });

    this.on('invalid', function(model, error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
  } 
});

//View
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({

  el: '#todo',
  tagName: 'li',
  template: _.template($('#todoTemplate').html()),

  events: {
    'dbclick label': 'edit',
    'click .edit': 'updateOnEnter',
    'blur .edit': 'close'
  },

  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.render();

  },

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    this.input = this.$('.edit');
    console.log(this.model.toJSON());
    return this;
  },

  edit: function() {
    //do something...
  },

  close: function() {
    //do something...
  },

  updateOnEnter: function() {
    //do something...
  }
});

var todoview = new TodoView();
console.log(todoview.el);

//Collection
var TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Todo
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to instantiate a `Model` or `Collection` and pass it to your View.  Otherwise, when the render method is called on your TodoView, `this.model` will be null.

For example, try rearranging the last few lines of your code like this:

```
//Collection
var TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Todo
});

var todos = new TodoList();

var todoview = new TodoView({model: todos});
```

From that point onward, you can modify todos (which is a `Collection`) and your view can listen to todos' events and re-render accordingly.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think you want to be passing `todos` into the view as `collection` and not `model`, so that you'd reference it inside the view as `this.collection`

Answer (score 4):

The answer in the other question is the answer to your question: you're not passing the model to the view when you instantiate the view.

```
var model = new Todo();
var todoview = new TodoView({model: model});
```

When you pass an object to a view's constructor, it looks for certain keys and attaches them directly to the view.

You can see which by looking at [Backbone's source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html) and searching for `viewOptions`.

That's how you get the `this.model` and `this.collection` automatically attached to the view's `this`.

Comment: "The answer in the other question is the answer to your question"? So why are you posting?

Comment: For added context: the question also asked about `this.model` and `this.collection`. Just trying to be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say, but I assume the error you are getting is occurring in the render() method.

Your problem is that you define a new type of model (`var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({...`) however you never instantiate it, nor do you pass the model to the todoview constructor.

So at the very least you need to do:

```
var todomodel = new Todo();

var todoview = new TodoView({
    model: todomodel
});
```